# How to use the following preprocessor statement

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
#define IS_THIS_CORRECT(X) if(X){}
```

I have this preprocessor statement defined in my project. I am trying to understand how to use this function.

Comment: That's not a function

Answer (score 1):

```
#define IS_THIS_CORRECT(X) if(X){}
```

It can be used to check if `X` (any value) is not zero or is not an empty string etc. You can do the following

```
IS_THIS_CORRECT("Hello")
else puts("The string is empty");
```

You'd better surround `X` with another pair of braces for more safety:

```
#define IS_THIS_CORRECT(X) if((X)){}
```

I suggest you to rename this preprocessor statement as `IT_IS_CORRECT` or even `IS_CORRECT` for more readability.

Comment: The extra pair of parentheses seems like a bad idea. `X` is already parenthesised, so adding it isn't necessary but will suppress a useful compiler warning for `IS_THIS_CORRECT(foo = bar)` with common compilers.

Comment: @Wintermute, I'm just following K&R's solutions. As far as I remember, they always say one must add these extra braces to the preprocessor statements like `#define add(x,y) (x)+(y)`. Try removing the braces and do `add(5+7,10+2)`

Comment: That is mostly true, but in `if(X)` there already is a pair of parentheses doing the job these parentheses are meant to do: ensuring that `X` is treated as a single entity. (Bad example, by the way; would have worked better with a `mul` macro).

Comment: @Wintermute, yes, not a really good one, but I think you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

As this is currently written, there is very little  possible *meaningful* use of it, except you want to handle only FALSE cases based on the value of `X`.

IMHO, you can re-write it as

```
#define IS_THIS_CORRECT(X) if(X)
```

then, you can use it like

```
 int p = 5;
 IS_THIS_CORRECT(X)
 {
      printf("yay !!!\n");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, but the only way this makes any sense to me is if it's supposed to be used as

```
IS_THIS_CORRECT(foo) else { do_something(); }
```

Still weird, though.